# Custom Delegate is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

For some reason my custom delegate is nil. Here is the code:

.h

```
@protocol AssignmentDelgate <NSObject>

-(void)newAssignment:(AssignmentInfo *)assignment;

@end
@property (nonatomic,weak)id<AssignmentDelgate> otherdelegate;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)addTheInfo:(id)sender {
    [self.otherdelegate newAssignment:self.assignmentInfo];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.otherdelegate); //Returning nil!
}
```

Another VC.h:

```
@interface AssignmentListViewController : UITableViewController<AssignmentDelgate,UITextFieldDelegate>

@property(strong,nonatomic) AddEditViewController *vc;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *alist;
```

Another VC.m

```
-(void)newAssignment:(AssignmentInfo *)assignment
{
    [self.alist addObject:assignment];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.vc.otherdelegate = self;
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Why the is the delegate nil?  I rewrote the app but it did not make a difference. Link to the project:
http://steveedwin.com/AssignmentAppTwo.zip

Comment: Where do you set the delegate?

Comment: @Kevin In another view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you're using a segue push.

You need to change your prepareForSegue to this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addAssignment"])
    {
        AddEditViewController *addEditController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [addEditController setOtherdelegate:self];
    }
}
```

There's no need to instantiate the self.vc as the storyboard is doing it for you.

**Explaination**
Since you're using storyboard, storyboard is actually instantiating your view controller. So you've made a link from the button to open up your next controller via a segue.

When you tap the button, its calling UIViewController's performSegueWithIdentifier: that method creates your destinationViewController for you which you can intercept in prepareForSegue.

So what was happening in your app, you created the AddEditViewController during viewDidLoad and were keeping it in memory, when you hit the button to bring up the AddEditViewController, you actually create a new instance of the class via segues.

Comment: Check if it is by doing NSLog(@"AddEditViewController: %@", self.vc); before setting its delegate. Otherwise is it possible that the delegate is being dealloced?

Comment: No the vc is not null

Comment: I added a link to the project

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you please explain why it is working now?